# JBoss Bean Statistics in Web-Console

Tags: jboss, ejb, javabeans

I would like to use the JBoss web-console to view bean statistics.  I read in a book ("JBoss: A Developer's Notebook") that bean invocation statistics are visible when drilling down through web-console's tree.  There's even a tantalizing screenshot of individual bean data showing "the total number of invocations processed is recorded, along with the
minimum, maximum, and average processing time."  However, when I drill down to my ejb module, I cannot get all the way to my beans.  At the ejb module level, I see xml on the right side of the screen, and the line: "Provides Statistics" shows false.  I have scoured the net for some way to 'turn on' beans so that they provide statistics.  Is there an element in my applications jboss.xml?

Oh: I should say that I'm using JBossAS 5.1.

Thanks for any help.

Josh

Comment: JBoss web console is deprecated in favor of Admin Console. Web Console will not be included in AS 6.0.

The book you refer to, JBoss: A Developer's Notebook, is very old. I can recommend "JBoss in Action".

What kind of statistics would you like to see? You could write a RHQ plugin and include it in the AS console.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I would like to know average execution speed of methods on stateless beans and also average execution speed of mdbs.  I will look for RHQ docs.  Still, I'm hoping to find a simple way to get the old web console behavior showing bean stats -- if there's some simple step I'm missing, I'd love to know it!